# Add infowindow to each marker (onclick marker)

Tags: google-maps-markers, infowindow

I need to get data from this array:

var array = [['USA', 'USA Office'], ['Canada', 'Canada Office']]

and create for each country marker with infowindow.

For now I have this (countries only):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

var map;

var elevator;

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.236107, -4.548056),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};       

map = new google.maps.Map(jQuery('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);

var addresses = ['Canada', 'Germany', 'France','USA','Ireland'];

for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {

    jQuery.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {

        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;          

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);           

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'addresses'
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            alert("Marker clicked");
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

    });

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

What's with your array? Are those Addresses or the same address in each subarray ?

I think you already know that you should geocode the addresses in your array in order for you to get the lat and lng so to display the marker.

There is this [Link](http://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/), Hope I helped.